# How can I convert table constructed with table1 package in R to Latex?

Tags: r, latex

I am trying to convert tables make with the table1 package for export into Latex.  I tried using xtable:

```
print(xtable(demo_table, type = "latex"), file = "Table2.tex")
```

but encountered the following error:

Error in UseMethod("xtable") :
no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "c('table1',    'html', 'character')"

Comment: Can you try `print(xtable(as.data.frame.matrix(demo_table), type = "latex"), file = "Table2.tex")`

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this and received the following error:   " first element used of 'length.out' argumentError in seq_len(ncols) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer"

Comment: Thanks.  When I tried this on my end, it is not showing the error.  probably different data, different errors. Thanks